# Who are the soldiers in John 18:3?

Tags: john, history

Does the "detachment of soldiers" refer to a *Roman* guard? If so, how large of a group? Or is it a different group of soldiers, perhaps a temple guard or Jewish soldiers if there were any at the time?

John 18:3 (NIV)

> So Judas came to the garden, guiding a detachment of soldiers and some officials from the chief priests and the Pharisees. They were carrying torches, lanterns and weapons.

Comment: @Soldarnal-See Answer by Ray Grant. Verse 12, and Acts 21:31 shed more light on this topic.  Take notice of the word "Commander" , a Roman chiliarch (General over 1,000 soldiers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know Greek but I checked some other translations and that helped a lot. NASB (the most literal* of all English translations) refers to that band of soldiers as a "Roman cohort"; NLV describes them as "contingent of Roman soldiers". Here are [some other translations](http://bible.cc/john/18-3.htm).

I read up in Nelsons New Illustrated Dictionary and found this on Cohort/Regiment:

> "One of ten divisions of ancient Roman Legion. The traditional Roman legion consisted of 6,000 soldiers. A regiment or cohort, consisted of about 600 men, although this number varied. The Book of Acts mentions the Italian Regiment (Acts 10:1; band, KJV; cohort, NRSV, REB, NASB) and the Augustan Regiment (Acts 27:1; band, KJV; Imperial Regiment, NIV)"

So we know that the band of soldiers were roman for sure, most likely the High Priests wanted to secure Jesus because they had been waiting so long to finally capture him in a situation that wouldn't stir up any trouble, so they could quickly kill Jesus and nobody would remember him. Ironically, things didn't go as planned for them because God's plan was that through Jesus' death and ressurection God would be glorified and our sins would be forgiven. The High Priests and Pharasies didn't realize that killing Jesus would make him even more famous and give them even more problems.

Obviously they didn't bring 600 men to arrest Jesus, I'm assuming that a selection of the Roman cohort was asked by the high priests probably decaalring to their (Roman) rulers that the situation required such extreme measures. At this time under Roman rule the arrests where performed by roman government and officials, including their army and special forces. In modern day terms it would be like taking the SWAT to arrest Jesus. You wouldn't take the entire team but a good amount becuase they new Jesus always had his disciples with him.

I hope that helps, my advice is to research it on [Biblios.com](http://biblios.com/), a great resource! Praise God that he used mans' hatred towards Jesus to put him on a cross where he took the wrath of our sins and waved victory over our bonds to sin!

<sub>* [Here is a good chart](http://www.tateville.com/translations.html) to see the most literal to least literal of all English translations.</sub>

Comment: Like far too many links from 10 years ago, this "good chart" no longer works. ¶ Please people, if it's useful information include it directly.

Answer (score 2):

When the apostle Paul heard of the plot to ambush him when he was in custody and about to be transported elsewhere, he got his family member to tell the Romans and they dispatched 470 soldiers to protect him from 40 Jews who were in hiding ready to kill him:

> Then he called two of his centurions and ordered them, “Get ready a detachment of two hundred soldiers, seventy horsemen and two hundred spearmen to go to Caesarea at nine tonight. (Acts 23:23)

Being so near the timeline of Christ this gives us an idea of how many soldiers may have been present at Christ's arrest.

Comment: Hi Seb, welcome to BH.SE! Please take the [Site Tour](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn more about how the site functions and what kinds of Questions and Answers to expect here. I've given your first answer a tidy up to include its reference and remove the advertisement from the end of it, as it wasn't really relevant to the answer itself.

Answer (score 1):

The Greek word translated as "cohort" in this scripture is σπεῖραν - "spira" or "speira".

This word can refer to "any band, company, or detachment, of soldiers" (Thayer).  In it's primary use, it refers to something "coiled up", like a rattlesnake.

It is very highly doubtful that Jesus was arrested by Romans;  Pontius Pilate had no idea who he was, nor were the charges brought upon Jesus Roman charges - they were Jewish charges.  It is also highly doubtful that 600 Roman soldiers would have been put under Jewish command for the sake of arresting one man.  And the logistics of getting 600 soldiers from Jerusalem, across the Kidron Valley to the Mount of Olives (and Gethsemane) makes for a coordinated, full-fledged military action - something that would have had to have been coordinated with a half-dozen Centurions.  And, the thing is this:  they didn't even know exactly where Jesus was;  Judas had to lead them there.

Comment: So who are the soldiers? You have provided a reasonable argument for who they **aren't**. Hint, the Temple Guard.

Answer (score 1):

**Commander** Instead of trying to figure out how big the Temple guard group was, or the definition of a Roman cohort, we have a hint of the size of this nocturnal adventurers, by the word for "commander" in John 18:12. (Gk. *chiliarchos*,Thayers p. 668-9; G.R. Berry, "Interlinear Greek N.T.")

The *detachment of soldiers* were led by a **commander**. This is the Roman word for a leader of 1,000 men! Whereas a "centurion" would be a leader of just a hundred men. (Of whom we are introduced to several times throughout Jesus's ministry.)

But since a hundred men did not always accompany the centurions Jesus interacted with, but just a small guard...so also, the use of this Commander that night, did not necessarily mean there were 1,000 Roman foot soldiers in attendance. But we can suppose the leader was satisfactorily accompanied by well-armed footmen.

**Paul's Arrest** An understanding is gained by checking in on the instance of Paul's arrest in Acts 21:31, when he was mobbed and beaten by the Jews:

> *While they were trying to kill him, news reached the commander of the Roman troops (to chiliarcho tes speires, Gk.) that the whole city of Jerusalem was in an uproar.  He at once took some officers and soldiers (stratiwtas kai ekatontarchous, Gk., "soldiers and centurions") and ran down to the crowd.*

The **commander** mentioned here, was over the whole soldier barracks at the fortress Antonia (a palace taken from Herod, north of the Temple mount). He was over several centurions with their armed men as is seen here in Acts. This is the same kind of "commander" and his men that marched on Jesus and His disciples on that fateful night. So the chief priests and Pharisees were quite serious about apprehending Jesus; they went *right to the top* to make sure there was no failure to get Jesus.
However, recall that when they asked Jesus if He be Jesus of Nazareth, the answer He gave (*I am He.*) had so much power and authority that they all "fell backward to the ground! *It wasn't military force that drove Christ to the cross, it was a greater power: the love of God!*

Since the scriptures never said "how many" of the Temple Guard there were, nor how many Roman soldiers there were, any interpretation is left up to speculation. (A "large crowd" was sent from the chief priests, scribes and elders (Mark 14:43, Temple guard, Luke 22:52). A "detachment of soldiers" with its "Commander" also was involved (John 18:3, 12).

No matter what, it would take a **night of prayer** to be able to handle this adversity in the Christian life!

Answer (score 0):

σπεῖρα is used both John 18:3 & 12. The commander is mentioned in v. 12. The commander is Jewish. No mention of a Roman commander. The Synoptic Gospels do not mention σπεῖρα at all. Even the NASB puts Roman cohort in italics to remind us they made this up. The KJV doesn't mention Roman soldier in any arrest record. The Greek-ENglish Lexicon of The New Testament and Other Early Christian Literature says it "probably means Roman cohort" because it means that everywhere else σπεῖρα is used.About half of the versions in BibleGateway.com do not use the term "Roman cohort" in their translations.

Comment: Paul - The way this is written makes it seem that you are saying "because the commander was Jewish, then the cohort must have been Jewish", but is that true?   Otherwise, I think perhaps John 18:12 would be very helpful:  `12 So the Roman cohort and the commander and the officers of the Jews, arrested Jesus and bound Him`

Comment: @PaulKranz-The Greek word for "commander" definitely refers to the Roman 'general' in charge of the Roman barracks (Fortress Antonia) who had several centurions under him. This Commander was the leader over 1,000 soldiers!  (See Acts 21:31)  Centurions led 100 men, or so.

Answer (score 0):

In Luke 22:52, while in the Garden, Jesus speaks to the chief priests, the officers of the temple guard, and the elders, who had come for him. Could the detachment of soldiers mentioned in John 18:3 be the officers of the temple guard (in other words, Levite soldiers)? Would the Greek word "speira" (Strong's 4686, NIV 5061) every be used for non-Roman soldiers? The two times it is used in the New Testament that are questionable are the two times it is used in John 18. The other two times it is used in the Gospels is in reference to Roman soldiers who interact with Jesus after he was arrested. Is there any way to know if it might be referring to the officers of the temple guard in John?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/48499)

Comment: @JEHilton-Thank you for your contribution. However, it is best to form your Answer as an _answer_. It would be less confusing to the reader. If there is no certitude available, more study ought to be done first.  Keep reading the Bible, it's great for the soul!

Answer (score -1):

It may very well have been a cohort (600) Roman soldiers who were called out to arrest Jesus.  During the early years of the first century CE there were multiple messianic pretenders as well as roaming bandits whom the Romans called brigands and criminals. Judas the Galilean,(Josephus) Athronges,(Josephus), the Egyptian (Josephus and Acts) and Theudas (Acts) are examples of what we would call religio-political agitators.  However in order for nascent Christianity to appeal to a Roman audience, Jesus's story is reinterpreted by his supporters after his capture and crucifixion. Sociology has described how difficult it is for disappointed members of a sect to accept reality, when their expectations are not met.

Comment: When you have a moment, please take our Tour to understand how we are different to other sites: https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: @JoelGoldman-Check the Greek word for "Commander" used here and compare it with Acts21:31. The Jewish priests "went to the top" to insure the capture of Jesus, their arch-nemesis!